# Re: AD9279 Board Redesign!

Tags: adc, schematics, component-selection, receiver

Has anyone worked with the Analog Devices AD9279 board?

If yes, please help me regarding this issue. We are trying to make a new ADC board of our own (to reduce the size of the board by removing the unnecessary components and reducing complexity).

We have the AD9279 chip with us and by seeing the schematic we will try to design a new board using OrCAD PCB design tool.

Can you please tell us what all components are really required to build the complete board and what all can be omitted?

And, what do these following components in the board capable of?

What are their functions and why are the following parts required or not: 
 1. AD9516 
 2. P606, P602, P603 
 3. MCL F 350 and MCL A 145 
 4. J502 
 5. AD8434 
 6. L614

Here, I am attaching the schematic of the AD9279
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B40LezSfQVrVUjhBQW96TlhQLU0/view?usp=sharing

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, but our answering your question is a short cut to you getting in trouble. You apparently do not understand the basics of the chip, and have not bothered to do basic research (as evidenced by your question about the function of parts like the AD9516).  Go back, do your homework, and come back here when you have questions which reflect some attempt to understand the board on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to page 35 of the datasheet:
http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9279.pdf

It gives you a very basic design so that you can start from there.
For other components, you need to read the datasheet to determine whether do you need it.